# How to light one or some LEDs with extremely low current?

Tags: voltage, current, rectifier

My device, which is called a triboelectric nanogenerator, can generate from about 20 to 50 volts open circuit (in AC) but only 0.1 micro ampere (100 nano ampere.) Are there any methods to light up some tiny LEDs? What do I need to install into the circuit if I use a full-wave rectifier?

Comment: 20V, 100nA is 2mW. This is a very low power, you might be able to find something that'll work, but it'll be hard. A 1V 0.5mA LED, needs 5mW, but they are common, so finding something with less power may well be possible. Maybe easiest to charge up a capacitor and then flash the LED for 0.25 seconds every 2 or 3 seconds. But that depends on the effieceny of you voltage converters. A full wave rectifier (4 diodes capacitor) is going to be required to get your AC to more usable (and storeable) DC.

Comment: If you convert about 40 V and 100 nA to 4 V, you may get about 500 nA assuming 50 % efficiency. I would recommend to a test before: Power a tiny LED with about 500 nA and look if you see something. If you don't see light from the LED, repeat the test in a very dark room without natural and artificial light. Wait about 15 minutes to achieve full sensitivity of your eyes. May be you will see light from the LED then. If you verified the LED in an acceptable illuminated room you may think about the converter.

Comment: @Puffafish "20V, 100nA is 2mW" I think you are wrong, it is only 2 µW, 0.002 mW.

Comment: define light up (lumen). LEDs emit proportional to current down to extremely low current. visibly in bright daylight is another story.

Comment: @Puffafish - And regardless of your original power estimate, you cannot apply 20 volts to an LED. It will limit the voltage to about 3 volts. And you cannot assume that the open-circuit power will be valid at much lower output voltages. For instance, if it behaves like a solar cell, it will maintain the current regardless of voltage, and the LED power will be 3 volts times .1 uA, or 0.3 uW.

Comment: I can increase the current up to nearly 1 micro ampere, even in that case, what kind of accessories that I need to build my circuit?

Comment: @tobalt I only need it to flash under the darkness, no need to be visible in bright daylight.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast so in order to light up the LED, I still need to provide enough current regardless of the Voltage?

Comment: @ĐứcKhánh - Yes. Or, to put it another way, unless you provide the current, you CANNOT produce the voltage. Look at any LED data sheet, and look at the current vs voltage curve. Zero current only applies at zero voltage. If you only need it to flash, the obvious way to deal with it is to use your generator to charge a capacitor, and at regular intervals drive an LED with a pulse. The greater the generator current, the higher the voltage in a given time, and the brighter the flash. 0.1 uA into a 1 uF cap will charge it at .1 volt/sec. After 100 secs you can flash an LED quite well. Briefly.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast So all I need is to build a full-wave rectifier with a capacitor, and when the capacitor is charged fully, the LED will flash, isn't it?

Comment: What frequency range can we expect?

Comment: @ĐứcKhánh - You did not specify that the signal is AC, and that makes life difficult, I don't know of a small-signal diode with a voltage limit near 20 volts and a reverse leakage current less than 0.1 uA. As a matter of fact, I don't know of one with a leakage current less than 1 uA. So the cap would never charge up. And any voltage sensor would have to have an input current at least a couple of orders of magnitude less than 0.1 uA, although there are op amps in that class, What I was thinking of was periodic dump of cap voltage throught the LED, and monitor the voltage.

Comment: @Jens it will generate electricity based on a very fast hand slapping motion, I do not know how fast I can achieve but I think it's pretty rapid.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Oh pardon me, yes my device generates AC signal, so the only solution is to increase my current to about 1 microampere?

Comment: @ĐứcKhánh - Sorry, but I was mistaken. You can do what you want. If you go to Digikey.com and search on diodes, you can find diodes with leakage currents under 1 nA, which is 1% of your nominal current, and fairly cheap, too.

Answer (score 2):

The circuity is tricky since the current are very small. Luckily there is a whole sub-industry dedicated to this kind of applications.

Search for "energy harvesting". The usual major manufactorers (TI, Analog and so on) usually have some dedicated chip for that purpose (resp. BQ25570 and LTC3588, *just for example*).

From what you told about your generator it seems something piezoelectric, so a quick search for "Piezoelectric energy harvesting" gives many interesting results.

Comment: Yeah, my project is about triboelectric (provide high voltage, low current) while piezoelectric (low voltage, high current). However, in some papers, their samples had like about 0.5 micro ampere and were still able to light up some LEDs. I will search for those manufacturers, but what kind of products I should buy from them?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [Wikipedia article on triboelectric nanogenerators,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanogenerator#Triboelectric_nanogenerator) it looks like you will need to capture and store the pulses of power generated by the your gadget.

Rectify the pulses, store the energy in a capacitor, discharge into the LED(s) when you have enough stored up.

Given the voltage levels you mention (20 to 50V,) you don't need to get fancy and use a voltage multiplier or something.  A simple bridge rectifier with a storage capacitor ought to do.

The devil's in the details, though.

1. You'll need to use low leakage diodes.  Probably not Schottky.
2. You'll need use low leakage capacitors.  Maybe ceramic (though the capacity would be limited,) maybe some other low leakage type with higher capacity.
3. You'll still want to use high efficiency LEDs.  The last time I needed high efficiency LEDs, the ones with the most light output per milliampere were orange ones.

Your circuit would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcH4K5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You collect energy until the capacitor is charged to some particular voltage, then close SW1.  The LED will light up for a time that depends on R1, C1, the charged voltage on C1, and the forward voltage of the LED.

---

The (somewhat) commonly available energy harvesting ICs (such as the [BQ25570](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25570.pdf)) are intended to work with low voltage sources.  They use a boost circuit to raise the low voltage to a higher voltage to charge a capacitor or battery.

The interesting thing is that they usually require that the battery have some charge in it to begin with.  The oscillator and other circuitry of the booster can't operate at the low input voltages expected.  The booster control and drive circuitry is all powered from the battery.

The catch to using such devices with your generator is that they are made for low input voltages.  The BQ25570, for example, can only accept up to about 5.1V from your generator.  Given that your generator can produces pulses up to 50V, the BQ25570 would probably not last for very long.

The [LTC3588](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/35881fc.pdf) is better in that it accepts up to 20V, but it still isn't rated for the full range of your device.

Comment: Therefore, I need to buy 5 low-leakage diodes, 1 low-leakage capacitor and some high-efficiency LEDs. What about the switch, does it need any specific requirements? Moreover, if you have time, would you mind posting the link to those items, since I am living in Korea but do not know Korean, thus I kinda need the production codes.

Answer (score 0):

With a classic bridge rectifier we only catch the enery peaks. This has a bad power factor.

I have difficulties to simulate such an energy source, but I assume, that any change in charge should be used and the amplitude may vary when it is derived from e.g. a human movement.

So I suggest this rectifier as an alternative, however there may be traps I currently don't see. Impedance matching may be bad here as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUj1n7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is there any specific requirement for the accessories? And could you kindly explain the location where I need to connect my device and the LED with this circuit? I am sorry I have no knowledge about electrical engineering.

Comment: @Đức Khánh There is no specific requirement except good cleaning after soldering to avoid leakage currents. R2 is a symbolic load, the LEDs in this case, but it is a good idea to use a switch like in the answer from JRE. Experiments with different values for C1 from 1 nF up to 1 uF can be useful. C2 just defines the maximum energy that can be collected, but a too big value will never reach a proper voltage.